# Why I i got different result in laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

So i tried to convert this sql query to laravel query builder

```
select jenis_data.id_jenisdata, jenis_data.id_level, jenis_data.nama_data, detail_A.id_kecamatan, satuan.satuan,
    detail_A.tahun, detail_A.angka as tahun_2018, detail_B.angka as tahun_2019, opd.id_opd, detail_A.id_bidang, detail_A.id_detaildata,
    opd.wali_data, jenis_data.perkecamatan from jenis_data

    left join detail_data as detail_A on jenis_data.id_jenisdata = detail_A.id_jenisdata
    left join opd on detail_A.id_opd = opd.id_opd
    left join satuan on jenis_data.id_satuan = satuan.id_satuan
    left join detail_data as detail_B on detail_A.id_jenisdata = detail_B.id_jenisdata
    AND detail_A.tahun = 2018 
    AND detail_B.tahun = 2019
    group by jenis_data.id_jenisdata, detail_A.id_kecamatan
```

and i came up with this query builder

```
DB::table('jenis_data')
    ->select('jenis_data.id_jenisdata','jenis_data.id_level','jenis_data.nama_data','detail_A.id_kecamatan','satuan.satuan',
    'detail_A.tahun','detail_A.angka as tahun_2018', 'detail_B.angka as tahun_2019', 'opd.id_opd', 'detail_A.id_bidang',
    'opd.wali_data','jenis_data.perkecamatan')
    
    ->leftJoin('detail_data as detail_A', 'jenis_data.id_jenisdata','=','detail_A.id_jenisdata')
    ->leftJoin('opd','detail_A.id_opd','=','opd.id_opd')
    ->leftJoin('satuan','jenis_data.id_satuan','=','satuan.id_satuan')
    ->leftJoin('detail_data as detail_B', 'detail_A.id_jenisdata', '=', 'detail_B.id_jenisdata')
    ->where('detail_A.tahun','2018')
    ->where('detail_B.tahun','2019')
    ->groupBy('jenis_data.id_jenisdata', 'detail_A.id_kecamatan')
    ->get();
```

the problem is i got different result, the result from laravel query builder is fewer than the sql query. Its like im doing inner join with the query builder rather than left join.

[result from sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzaqU.png)

[result from query builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jnXi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first query, there is no "where" clause.

In query builder...

```php
->leftJoin('detail_data as detail_B', function ($join) {
    $join->on('detail_A.id_jenisdata', '=', 'detail_B.id_jenisdata')
        ->where('detail_A.tahun','2018')
        ->where('detail_B.tahun','2019');
})
```

Comment: i've read somewhere that the AND condition for laravel query builder is using WHERE clause

Comment: The problem is in SQL query, not the query builder.

Comment: thank you.. it works :D what is that? can i get the keyword for future reference?

Comment: look: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses